# pjax (ajax-based page loading) and user scrolling

Tags: ajax, pjax

Let assume I've got few long pages, and I want to use [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax). When I scroll one page to the end, then click a link invoking pjax reload, then the second page's viewport starts at the end of page (while without pjax the browser would start on the top of page).

Other drawback I see is that when clicking back button the previous page's viewport is again preserved, and not returned back to what it was on the previous page.

This behavior is annoying and not usable. Is it possible to simulate the standard browser's behavior with pjax?

Answer (score 5):

My solution to this is to bind to the `pjax:end` event and just scroll the page to the top; the only slight downside is that the back button still doesn't remember the scroll position and will always start at the top.

```
$('#your-container').bind('pjax:end', function() {
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: I did the same thing by adding the following inside the pjax click function: $('body,html').animate({
         scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);